# Show/Hide Left and Right Border in WPF RichTextBox codebehind?

Tags: c#, wpf, border, richtextbox

I want to hide/show WPF `RichTextBox` left border sometimes in code behind and also for right border sometimes.

Can this be achieved?

I've already tried in XAML like this `borderthickness ="3,3,0,3"`.  It hides my right side, now I need to show that right side border and also hide my right side border.

How do I do that?

**Updated:**

```
<Window x:Class="View.SingleLineTextMode"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="SingleLineTextMode" Height="300" Width="300" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStyle="None" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Background="Black">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MyStyle" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type RichTextBox}">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="0,5,0,0"/>

            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RichTextBox}">
                        <Border x:Name="bg" BorderBrush="Yellow" BorderThickness="3,3,0,3" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"  IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True" CanContentScroll="False" />
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="bg" Value="Yellow"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="bg" Value="3,3,0,3"/>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="bg" Value="Yellow"/>
                                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="bg" Value="3,3,0,3"/>
                            </Trigger>

                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <!--<RichTextBox Name="txtAppendValue" Height="60" Width="1920" Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}" Margin="0,0,-10,0" FontSize="60" FontFamily="Arial"  IsReadOnly="True" Focusable="False" Cursor="Arrow" BorderThickness="3,3,3,3" IsUndoEnabled="False" UndoLimit="0" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" VirtualizingPanel.CacheLength="2,3" VirtualizingPanel.CacheLengthUnit="Page" TextBlock.LineHeight="100" Padding="0">
        </RichTextBox>-->
        <RichTextBox Name="txtAppendValue" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Height="60" Width="1920" Style="{StaticResource MyStyle}" Margin="0,0,0,0"  FontSize="40" FontFamily="Arial"  IsReadOnly="True" Focusable="False" Cursor="Arrow"  IsUndoEnabled="False" UndoLimit="0" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" VirtualizingPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" VirtualizingPanel.CacheLength="2,3" VirtualizingPanel.CacheLengthUnit="Page" TextBlock.LineHeight="100" >
        </RichTextBox>
        <Label Name="lblStatusUpdate" ></Label>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The above one is my XAML.

```
txtAppendValue.BorderThickness=new Thickness("0,3,0,3");
```

But its not working.

Regards
Arjun

Comment: The problem is that you are using the style, I've made an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the same thing from code like this:

```
myRichTextBox.BorderThickness = new Thickness(3,3,0,3);
```

Then if all borders need to have same thickness, you can use only one number:

```
myRichTextBox.BorderThickness = new Thickness(3);
```

**Edit:**

Since you are using style, you can define multiple styles and then switch between them:

```
<Style x:Key="MyStyleNoBorders" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type RichTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RichTextBox}">
                <Border x:Name="bg" BorderBrush="Yellow" BorderThickness="0,3,0,3" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"  IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True" CanContentScroll="False" />
                </Border>                       
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
<Style x:Key="MyStyleBothBorders" BasedOn="{x:Null}" TargetType="{x:Type RichTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type RichTextBox}">
                <Border x:Name="bg" BorderBrush="Yellow" BorderThickness="3" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost"  IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True" CanContentScroll="False" />
                </Border>                       
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Make sure your `RichTextBox` is not too wide to fit the screen, or you will not be able to see the borders. Then in code just use a call to change styles:

```
txtAppendValue.Style = FindResource("MyStyleNoBorders") as Style;
```

and

```
txtAppendValue.Style = FindResource("MyStyleBothBorders") as Style;
```

Comment: @ Nemanja : No man.its not working 'txtAppendValue.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 3, 0, 3);' I mean not hide my left border.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you... Just use the number greater than 0 for border that you wish to see, check the `Thickness` constructor here: [Thickness Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms587975(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @ Nemanja : Yes.it increase the border thickness,when we use some numbers.but i need to hide that border.

Comment: Doesn't setting the number to 0 for specific border give the result that you need? Or are you looking for a different way to hide border?

Comment: Actually,it didn't work. Initially I am using Margin values like 0,0,0,0.and borderthickness ="3,3,0,3" it fine and hide right side.after that i have to change borderthickness ="0,3,0,3" for both side hide and 0,3,3,3 for left side hide.but it didnt work.

Comment: It works fine for me, `BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 3, 0, 3)` hides both, `BorderThickness = new Thickness(0, 3, 3, 3)` hides only left and `BorderThickness = new Thickness(3, 3, 0, 3)` hides only right border. Make sure you are setting the value for correct control.

Comment: Great man.thank u.But y its not working in using myRichTextBox.BorderThickness = new Thickness(3,3,0,3);

Comment: @ Nemanja : Actually border problem solved.but after using txtAppendValue.Style = FindResource("MyStyleBothBorders") as Style; autoscroll happened till starting word.How can solve it?

Comment: When you set style, it is overriding all the values from the control with the values from the style. Maybe it would be easier for you not to use style, but instead set only the values that you need directly, either from XAML or from code. That way, command for setting the `BorderThickness` would also work, and then you could also look at the scroll problem that you have separately.